# Can't creating points using folium add_child

Tags: python, folium

Python rookie here. I am making a google map API request for places, I get back a list and then i want to map the points (lat,long).  I have achieved this task using the 'mapit' script, but I wanted to be able to use more features in folium ((ie)layercontrol etc).  The 'for' loop I have written just maps the last item in the the list it creates.  I understand why it is doing that, but don't understand how map all of them in one layer.  appreciate any feedback

```
import folium
import pandas
import urllib3.request
import json, requests

url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"
google_api = "mykey"

#google API request code
qry = input('Search query: ')
r = requests.get(url + 'query=' + qry + '&key=' + google_api)
response = r.json()
results = response['results']

for i in range(len(results)):
    location = results[i]['geometry']['location']
    lat = location['lat']
    lng = location['lng']
    nameP = results[i]['name']
    latLong = []
    latLong.append(tuple([lat,lng, nameP]))

print(latLong)


map = folium.Map(location=[39.712183, -104.998424], zoom_start=5)
point_layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Query Search")

point_layer.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, lng], radius=10,
    popup=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng), 
    tooltip=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng),
    fill=True,  # Set fill to True
    color='red',
    fill_opacity=1.0))..add_to(Map)

map.add_child(point_layer)
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())  
map.save("Map1.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 tips before the solution:

- Do not use `map` as a variable name. `map` is a reserved word in Python. Folium users normally use the variable name `m` for maps
- Your code contains a `SyntaxError`. You have 2 dots in `fill_opacity=1.0))..add_to(Map)`

The **solution**: you need to iterate as well on each lat-long pair with a for loop and then combine them on a layer. There are other ways to accomplish this without iterating (such as geoJson) but in your case this is the simplest one. Check the following code:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[39.712183, -104.998424], zoom_start=5)
point_layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Query Search")

latLong = [(36.314292,-117.517516,"initial point"),
           (40.041159,-116.153016,"second point"),
           (34.014757,-119.821985,"third point")]

for lat,lng,nameP in latLong:
    point_layer.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, lng], radius=10,
        popup=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng), 
        tooltip=str(nameP) + " Lat: " + str(lat) + " , Long: " + str(lng),
        fill=True,  # Set fill to True
        color='red',
        fill_opacity=1.0)).add_to(m)

m.add_child(point_layer)
m.add_child(folium.LayerControl())  
m.save("Map1.html")
```

If you want a better looking tooltip or popup, insert the text in a folium.Iframe with Html, as seen [here in the fancy popup section](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Popups.ipynb)

Map:

[example of the map with the previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWV5s.png)